# Is there a way to limit the maximum number of processing records in a Job of Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is there a way to limit the maximum number of processing records in a job of Spring Batch?

I need to have a configuration by which I could control the maximum number of records that can be processed by a job.

The job is reading from Database using a Stored Procedure, I could limit the maximum number of fetched rows in the Procedure itself, but I am looking for any features provided in Spring Batch for that and I am not able to find it yet.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you have tried yet?

Comment: The job is reading from Database using a Stored Procedure, I could limit the maximum number of fetched rows in the Procedure itself, but I am looking for any features provided in Spring Batch for that and I am not able to find it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a custom `ItemReader` holds record count and return `null` ('stop reading') when the limit is reached.
 Store variable used to count records into step-execution context.
 Remember to let your custom `ItemReader` implements `ItemStream`: in this manner SB will save/restore record count into/from context automatically.
 I hope I was clear, English is not my native language.