# Schedule a batch mail job in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I need to send approx 40 - 50000 mails depending upon user selection. These mail id are stored in database. There can be any number of mail. A  dedicated mail server is setup for this. I don't want them to end up in spam.
I want to send mail of approx 5000 per hour so as to avoid getting blacklisted. I want to schedule a batch mail job where all mails are send and failed mails are retried. So as to avoid. The batch job is scheduled when user start it and he  has control to stop and also log of mails sent.
This is what I found to start and stop the job but there can be better ways to implement this. Please help

```
  @RequestMapping("start")
ResponseEntity<Void> start() {
    scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(sendMail(), FIXED_RATE);

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping("stop")
ResponseEntity<Void> stop() {
    scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

These mails are send to a closed group of students and this is unrelated to spamming or email marketing .
I am new to spring batch processing and have no idea how to proceed and using spring boot.
Note: This is unrelated to email marketing or spamming.

So far I have thought of a different approach to save all the mails to be sent in a mail queue

Mail Queue Entity:

```html
package com.iitraa.alumnus.iitAlumnus.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class MailQueue {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private  int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    @ManyToOne
    private MailJobs mailJobs;
  
    private boolean complete;



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setMailJobs(MailJobs mailJobs) {
        this.mailJobs = mailJobs;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public MailJobs getMailJobs() {
        return mailJobs;
    }

    
}
```

Mail Jobs is each job in which number of mail are scheduled

```html
package com.iitraa.alumnus.iitAlumnus.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class MailJobs {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private  String subject;
    @Column
    private String mailMessage;
    @Column
    private String fromEmail;
    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Year> years= new HashSet<>();;

    public Set<Year> getYears() {
        return years;
    }

    public void setYears(Set<Year> years) {
        this.years = years;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I am adding mail queue which contains all mail to be sent and then process a hourly run above start method sendMail() which will fetch a  batch of mails from the mailQueue send them and delete from the table always until the table is empty.
I dont know a better way or how to implement it using spring batch mail schedule.
That's what I need help with.

Comment: Please share the code of your job/steps definition to be able to help you.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have added code I am trying to implement but rather I am finding a better and clean way to achieve the same thing. May be spring batch provides a better way to achieve this but I cant understand how will I proceed

Comment: Are those emails already  generated in the `MailJobs` table and you want to read them and send them using Spring Batch? So if I understand correctly an item is a record from this table and you want to send only 5000 emails per job execution. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Correct  . Currently All user data is stored in userdetails table. When admin send mail all recipients are copied to mailQueue table which is mapped to mailJobs.  This process of copying is redundant and takes too much time as there are 50000 records. Once mail is sent the records are deleted. Please suggest a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to limit the maximum number of processing records in a Job of Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091668/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-maximum-number-of-processing-records-in-a-job-of-spr)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Here each mail is a job or they will be divided in batches. Please provide code reference to implement if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217902/discussion-between-john-and-mahmoud-ben-hassine).